# Can we force a c# compiler to run constructor first?

Tags: c#

As c# **field initializers** run before **constructor**. Is there any way to force the compiler to run constructor first?

Thanks @Jonathan, But I need to know, why?

Comment: Make constructor static. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx

Comment: @Saleem And this is why you should be able to down-vote comments. The OP asked nothing about `static` fields; your comment is completely irrelevant, off-topic, and distracting.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I respect your opinion but my answer is how to execute constructor before fields initializer. This is a way, not an ideal.

Comment: @Saleem No, I'm sorry, but you're completely off-base; a static constructor is *completely different* from an ordinary constructor, as `static` fields are *completely different* from ordinary member fields. If you don't understand the difference, I suggest you stop using the keyword `static` immediately until you understand.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: It's not merely that the comment is unhelpful; it's simply wrong. Static field initializers run *before* static constructor bodies, the same as instance field initializers run before instance constructor bodies. Static constructors are not different in this regard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

If you for some reason care about the order, initialize your fields in the constructor.

Caring about the order of initialization seems like a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).